# Как отрендерить вид yii2, если нет подключения к базе?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii

Есть `class DbConnection extends Connection`, который переопределяет метод `open()`

```html
public function open(){
        try { parent::open(); }
        catch(\Exception $e){
        if (!\Yii::$app->request->isConsoleRequest) {
               \Yii::$app->isMaintenance = true;
               \Yii::$app->isDbFree = true;
               echo \Yii::$app->runAction('site/maintenance');
            } else { echo($e->getMessage());
         }
   \Yii::$app->end();
  }

 }
```

при таком исполнении, если нет подключения к базе, то рендериться вид, но получается ошибка:

> yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent

Если сделать свой класс:

```html
$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host='.getenv('DB_HOST').';dbname='.getenv('DB_NAME'),
    'username' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
 'attributes' => $attributes
]);
$test = $db->getIsActive();
if(!$test) {
  ??????
}
```

Как теперь запустить приложении yii2, и отрендерить вид заглушки(.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что не надо все в кучу лепить. Зачем тогда вообще фреймворк, если в класс коннекта приходится пихать echo?

Если нужна база и при этом нет соединения, то прилетит Exception. Что мешает его отловить и отрисовать необходимые виды?

```
switch(true){
  case ($exception instanceof ForbiddenHttpException):
    $content = $this->render('errors/403', $params);
    break;
  case ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException):
    $content = $this->render('errors/404', $params);
    break;
  default :
    $content = $this->render('errors/unknown', $params);
}
```